# Is it possible to not use lower-case for word cloud in AnyChart?

Tags: anychart

I like the word cloud functionality in AnyChart, but is it possible to not use all lower-case words? I've only been able to make it use all upper-case instead, weirdly enough by using `fontVariant('small-caps')`. I would just like it to maintain the casing of the input strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to override this behavior with the current version of the library (8.7.0 November 2019). The tag cloud chart ignores the case (transform to lower-case) to find matches. Then it renders words in the lower-case. We will take into account this requirement for future updates.

Comment: This is a good answer (as in from a reliable source), but bad functionality.